# find a keyword in a collection and return it

Tags: java

I have a collection i added CD, DVD, book information into hashsets.
Each one has a keyword and i would like to do a search for a specific keyword and return the specific book,CD,dvd... heres the output to give you an idea..

```
-Book-
Author:   Robert A. Heinlein
# pages   325
title: Starship Troopers
keywords: [science fiction, war, weapons]

-Music-
band:     Grateful Dead
# songs:  12
members:  [Jerry Garcia, Bill Kreutzman, Keith Godcheaux]
title: Europe In '72
keywords: [acid rock, sixties, jam bands]


-Movie-
director: Sofia Coppola
# scenes: 14
cast:     [Bill Murray, Scarlett Johansson]
title: Lost In Translation
keywords: [Japan, loneliness]


>>> items for keyword: science fiction

none

>>> items for keyword: jam bands

none


C:\Java\a03>
```

I have 3 classes.

1. Main()
2. Library - this is where i do all the adding of cd, DVD, books. lookups, etc
3. Items class(CD class, DVd class, book class) using inheritance..

in main() i am sending in information to the library class to add to the sets.
then i print out all the books, cd, movies just added.

then i do a lookup for a specific keyword.
And this is where i am having problems. i wrote a getkeyword function in CD, DVD, book class.

What i want to do is get the keyword and then see if they match and then return it as a collection.

here is main() i will only show some of it to keep this short - i will not show you how i am adding since it works good..

```
printItemsForKeyword(out, "science fiction");
printItemsForKeyword(out, "jam bands");
printItemsForKeyword(out, "xxx");


private static void printItemsForKeyword (PrintStream out, String keyword)
{
    Collection<Item>    items;

    out.printf(">>> items for keyword: %s\n\n", keyword);
    items = library.itemsForKeyword(keyword);
    printItems(out, items);
}
```

now here in the library class is where i need help
in the itemsForKeyword(String keyword) function...

so, the first thing i am trying to find is "Science Fiction"

I think i need to cast item since item has the CD, DVD, book classes and i need to return a colection???

right now i am trying to return key and it wont since its incompatable with the return.

```
public class Library
{
private Set<Item> theCDs = new HashSet<Item>();
private Set<Item> theDVDs = new HashSet<Item>();
private Set<Item> theBooks = new HashSet<Item>();


public Collection<Item> itemsForKeyword(String keyword)
{

    Item key = new Item();            
    ((CD)key).getKeyword();    // i dont think i am even doing this right

    if(key.equals(keyword))
    {
        return key;             // cant return key
       }



    return null;
}
```

I did define a getKeywords() function in each of the classes below.

Here is the Items class since you will need to look it over..

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.*;


class Item
{

private String title;



public String toString()
{

String line1 = "title:    " + title + "\n";
return line1;
}


public void print()
{

System.out.println(toString());


}


public Item()
{

}

public Item(String theTitle)
{

title = theTitle;

}

public String getTitle()
{
return title;
}



}

class CD extends Item
{

private String artist;
private String [] members;
private String [] keywords;
private int number;





public CD(String theTitle, String theBand, int Snumber, String... keywords)
{
    super(theTitle);
    this.artist = theBand;
    this.number = Snumber;
    this.keywords = keywords;

}


  public void addband(String... member)
{
    this.members = member;

}

public String getArtist()
{

    return artist;

}

public String [] getMembers()
{
 return members;   
}


public String [] getKeyword()
{

    return keywords;

}


public String toString()
{



   return  "-Music-" + "\n"
     + "band:     " + artist + "\n" 
     + "# songs:  " + number + "\n" 
     + "members:  " + Arrays.toString(members) 
     + "\n" + super.toString() 
     + "keywords: " + Arrays.toString(keywords) 
     + "\n" + "\n" ;

}


public void print()
{


    System.out.println(toString());

}

  }


class DVD extends Item
{

private String director;
private String [] cast;
private int scenes;
private String [] keywords;


public DVD(String theTitle, String theDirector, int nScenes, String... keywords)
{
    super(theTitle);
    this.director = theDirector;
    this.scenes = nScenes;
    this.keywords = keywords;

}

public void addmoviecast(String... members)
{
    this.cast = members;


}

public String [] getCast()
{
    return cast;

}



public String getDirector()
{
    return director;
}

public String [] getKeyword()
{

    return keywords;

}




 public String toString()
 {

    return "-Movie-" + "\n"
     + "director: " + director + "\n"
     + "# scenes: " + scenes + "\n"
     + "cast:     " + Arrays.toString(cast) + "\n"
     + super.toString() 
     + "keywords: " + Arrays.toString(keywords) 
     + "\n" + "\n" ;

 }

 public void print()
 {

  System.out.println(toString());  

 }

 }


class Book extends Item
{

private String author;
private int pages;
private String [] keywords;


public Book(String theTitle, String theAuthor, int  nPages, String... keywords)
{
    super(theTitle);
    this.author = theAuthor;
    this.pages = nPages;
    this.keywords = keywords;

}


public String getAuthor()
{

    return author;

}

public String [] getKeyword()
{

    return keywords;

}




public void print()
{

    System.out.println(toString());  

}


 public String toString()
{

    return "-Book-" + "\n"
     + "Author:   " + author + "\n" 
     + "# pages   " + pages + "\n"
     + super.toString() 
     + "keywords: " + Arrays.toString(keywords) 
     + "\n" + "\n" ;


}    
}
```

the reason why i think i need to do sometype of cast is because i had to when i added
bandmembers..

```
public void addBandMembers(Item musicCD, String... members)
{


    ((CD)musicCD).addband(members);


}
```

So, what can i do to find a keyword in the items and return those?
would it be better to look directly at the sets and do some type of cast to get it to return? im just stumped..

Thank you..

Comment: first off, put 'keywords' into the Item base class where it belongs.

Comment: Just a tip: please pay attention to code formatting. There's lot of unnecessary whitespace and the indentation is poor. This may confuse and annoy a lot of readers and cause them to move along your question. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, just doing `Ctrl+Shift+F` will help a lot.

Comment: I agree.. however, i am using bluej.. its hard to indent

Answer (score 1):

Create an index (`SortedMap<String, List<Item>>`) relating keywords to the items they represent.  When an object is added to the library, map it to each of its keywords in the index, adding new keywords as needed. Search the index to find the objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow what you're trying to ask, but I hope the following is what you're after. It looks to me that you're chiefly concerned with getting a Collection of Items, which you want done using the method `public Collection<Item> itemsForKeyword(String keyword)`.

In this method, you should do the following:

1. Create an empty Collection (either a HashSet or TreeSet depending on whether you need it sorted).
2. Loop through theCDs. For each Item, get its keywords.
3. Loop through keywords. If you find one that `equals` (or `equalsIgnoreCase`) the one passed in, add the Item to the Collection you created in 1.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 for theDVDs and theBooks.
5. Return the Collection you created in 1.

A couple of other things:

- I'd suggest that you rename `getKeyword` to `getKeywords`, since that's what it's returning.
- For the purposes of this method, you would be better off having keywords in a HashSet so that you can do `item.getKeyword().containsKey(keyword)` instead of the looping in 3. If you do this and need it the method to be case insensitive, you would need to store keywords in all lower case or all upper case, and add in a step 0 to convert the passed in keyword to the correct case before searching. Also, this may not be the way to go if you need to extensively use keywords as an array elsewhere.

Comment: you said" your better off having keywords in a hashset so you can do:" item.getKeyword().containsKey(keyword) what is item defined as?

Comment: An instance of your Item class.

Comment: so, something like this.. Item obj = new item(); obj.getKeyword().containsKey(keyword); ??